Latest implementation of wallet adapter
Can anyone please share latest implementation of Solana Wallet Adapter and contract call using front end?

You can find the repo here, -> https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter
Different folks have different ways to accomplish this. For Some, they'll have the IDL in the frontend repo and call their program ixs from it.
The approach most people take is to create a separate NPM package as an SDK to interact with their program and also enable others to be able to do so.
Here is an example using soundwork SDK for their programs
You should also check out Codama, which automates this process and instead generates IDLs for you -> https://github.com/codama-idl/codama/
